# How to download all repository using apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

Is there any way to just download all Ubuntu repositories using `apt-get`? I am looking for something like :

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only *
```

So that I can access the downloaded repository in the directory `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: Yeah. Indeed i have changed the address of the repositories to a local computer and i want to download all from there.

Comment: You probably wan't something like: http://apt-mirror.github.io/

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work properly when i change the address of the repositories in `mirror.list`. Where as the same addresses work well when defined in `sources.list`. So i am looking for an alternate way.

Comment: Do you have enough disk-space to house all of those packages?

Comment: @blade19899 Yeah. I have more than 100 GB of free space.

Comment: I'm not sure if 100GB is gonna be enough. But, i don't really know how large the entire trusty repository is. Do let us know!

Comment: @blade19899 mirroring binary amd64 and i386 for `trusty`,`trusty-security` and `trusty-updates` (`main`,`universe`,`multiverse`,`restricted`) takes me about 103GB.

Comment: @muru, Nice. But, in what kind of real-life situation do you need this. Except to install when u don't have Internet. Sooner or later you still have to update them local packages.

Comment: @blade19899 Local mirror for college labs and other student use. The mirror is synced each day.

Comment: @blade19899 You can significantly decrease the outgoing traffic in an organization if someone downloads it and others get locally.

Comment: @Nejat for that purpose you should really use caching proxies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, this is not a convenient way. Instead of this you should  use the method mention [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal). But as an answer to the question.

- First create a file which contains names of all the available
  packages using `apt-cache`.

  ```
  apt-cache  dumpavail |grep -oP "(?<=Package: ).*" >> packagelist
  ```

  This will create a file `packagelist` with all the available packages.
- Now create a simple script to download all the packages present in
  the file `packagelist`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  for package in `cat packagelist`
   do
      apt-get install -y --download-only $package   
   done
  ```
- Save it.
- Make it executable using

  ```
  chmod +x your_script_name
  ```
- Now open terminal and login as root

  ```
  sudo -i
  cd /folder/of/you/script
  ./you_script_name
  ```

It will download all the available package depending upon your `/etc/apt/sources.list`
 in `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called apt-cacher. You can [check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) this link for more info.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not get all repositories. When you get some packages just those are cached. I want some way to cache them all.

Comment: Then you can use apt-mirror [check this link](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-apt-cacher)