# How to download most of Ubuntu Software Centre?

Tags: apt, downloads

I want to download entire multiverse repository
I know it maybe several GBs around 20, but I want to.
NOTE:I ONLY WANT TO DOWNLOAD AND WILL INSTALL LATER using `dpkg -i [pkg]`
First created a file which contains names of all the available packages using apt-cache.

> apt-cache  dumpavail |grep -oP "(?<=Package: ).*" >> packagelist

This will create a file packagelist with all the available packages.
i want to understand the working of `apt-cache dumpavail` command. i know >> is there to append and creates a file package list and all, but didn't get that grep (?<=package: ) and it's working so ones understood i don't have to memorize that stuff.

Comment: I just said I got it wrong http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ has no .debs only an index (list) of them, it won't get you what you want. To download it click on `Contents-amd64.gz` it is a link, you will see, just a text file.

Comment: ok but neither will http://askubuntu.com/questions/531403/how-to-download-all-repository-using-apt-get, i want an answer not a comment

Comment: sorry, don't waste your time, i will try. i am just unable to follow it. it's complicated.

Comment: shall   i edit this into a vpn question or just ask another.

Comment: Why is it complicated ? why not just say "I don't understand that, can you explain for me ?" So you don't understand the * ? That mean's all files contain . and something after it, so .* is every file with an extension in the repo (.debs .gz .tar .txt) so that's all of them. Don't ask a new question, just use comments to ask for advice, when you edit your question like that it comes off as `I tried this it did not work`. I will help you, but use comments, to ask for clarification, just so we are clear and on the same page :)

Comment: Next you must copy that script to a blank text file, save it as `repo.sh` in /home and then run `chmod +x repo.sh` in your home folder or right click and `make executable`. Now when you run this it will download the repo, run it with `sudo ./repo.sh`. Does this make it a bit easier to understand ? Please do ask for help.

Comment: how much will be the total size of download like 10GB or 100GB freaking? can't afford it dude. i will remove some packages then. does it have ppa, ex:indicator-brightness?

Comment: are only free packages  included, so i don't end up with commercial-ware and waste my download capacity?

Comment: I don't know how big it is, I am running it now I will let you know, it is taking a while, but it works. It will download all your currently active repos, so go to the `software and updates` app and just disable the one you don't want to download (3rd party ones like `get.deb` or whatever) and re enable them after the download is complete.

Comment: `apt-cache dumpavail` Dumps all available (`dumpavail`) sources in apt's cache (`apt-cache`) to a file called `packagelist`. You don't have to memorize any thing, run `apt-cache dumpavail |grep -oP "(?<=Package: ).*" >> packagelist` to overwrite the list, then run `repo.sh` to download it, that is the only steps after the first time.

Comment: my `packagelist` is created in /root. is it right, as even with sudo i got permission denied, or did u do with sudo instead of su/sudo -i or change it's location

Comment: No, don't run `sudo apt-cache dumpavail |grep -oP "(?<=Package: ).*" >> packagelist` just `apt-cache dumpavail |grep -oP "(?<=Package: ).*" >> packagelist` it should be in the /home of your current user for easy running.

Comment: OK My download is taking ages but seems the download will be 103GB ish for default repos.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248955/61798

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mirror for your own. One tool to do this is `debmirror`. It's downloading the complete repository and saving it to your hard disc. Once this has done, you can add the local folder to your apt-configuration and using it instead of remote mirrors. Or you can provide a webserver to offer it as mirror to your company.

There is a [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror) about.

However, packages are stored inside http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ but without the meta data you cannot be sure it's not changed etc. (Inside packages.gz there are crypto-hashes stored)